# Alienware-kbl is not installing due to python3-usb

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dependencies, python3

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and I am trying to install alienware-kbl on my laptop to fix the lights on the keyboard. I have used it in the past with Ubuntu 14.04 and everything worked fine until a few days ago. I have tried re-installing Ubuntu several times and tried `apt-get -f install`. I have allowed access to the universal repository and I have checked to make sure python3 is installed(it comes with Ubuntu). This is the error I get:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
alienware-kbl: Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.10) but 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6 is to be installed 
Depends: python3-usb but it is not going to be installed
```

I switched to Ubuntu a couple of months ago from windows and any help would be appreciated as I am going insane with these lights.

Answer (score 0):

The creator answered the question on his site. These are his suggestions and I hope they help someone in the future if they need it.:

The libgtk-3-0 dependence is alright, ignore it.

Python3-usb dependence on Ubuntu is only available since the 15.04 version. If you don’t want to update to 15.10 try this:

Download and install some Debian package of python3-usb (Ubuntu wily, debian, etc) then reinstall the package.

Install python3-usb thought python3-pip then force the alienware-kbl installation.

Install python3-usb as you want (even just coping the .py file) then installing the tar.gz